# steps involved in object instantiation.

Tags: java

I have a very basic doubt in Java. I have these following classes:

userViewtest.java:

```
package source;

public class userViewTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
           userView usersView = new userView();
           usersView.printUsers();
    }
}
```

Then userView.java:

```
package source;
    public class userView{
        String test="My test String";
        public void printUsers(){
    System.out.println(test);

        }
    }
```

Please forgive if this is stupid question but when userView object is created at that time does the String test get instantiated, because when I call usersView.printUsers(); the String test prints perfectly. But I didn't know when objects are created the variables inside load the values.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is a class member. Each `userView` (Should be named `UserView`) *object* has the value of `test`.

When you create an *object*, you allocate memory for it and return a reference to that memory, where you have this variable. I advise you to go through a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) to better understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the moment you create an object, java creates space for your object on heap and store your object there, which contains instance variables (*in your case **test** is the variable*)

See this for detailed explanation `--->` http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Object_Lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear. And you should use uppercase to start a class name.  Since that will lead to confusion when you are trying to call the object since both class name and variable name are same.

```
UserView usersView = new userView(); // Here, you are creating a new instance of 
                                     // userView which refers to the same memory location
```

This `usersView` contains all attribute of `UserView`. Now you can invoke them by calling them by the method name.